# Programatically remove item from search index immediately in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-search

Is it possible to remove item from search index programatically SharePoint 2013? I know there was tool called "docpush" in SharePoint 2010 but i couldn't find it in SP2013.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have central admin access? If so, just remove it from the search center, /_layouts/15/searchadmin/searchresultremoval.aspx

Comment: @EricAlexander Is it possible to do it programatically?

Answer (score 1):

**Remove an item from the search index**

- To remove an item from the search index
- Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an
  administrator for the Search service application.
- On the SharePoint Central Administration home page, in the
  Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
- On the Manage Search Applications page, click the Search service
  application.
- On the Search Administration page, in the Diagnostics section, click
  Crawl Log.
- On the Crawl Log page, click URL View.
- Do one of the following:

  - If you know the URL of the item that you want to remove, type the URL
    in the box.
  - If you do not know the URL of the item that you want to remove,
    search for it by using the filters Content Source, Status or Message.
- Click Search.
- Find and point to the URL of the item that you want to remove, click
  the arrow and then click Remove the item from the Index.
- In the confirmation dialog that appears, click OK to confirm that you
  want to remove the item from the index.
- Verification: the text Removed from the search index by Admin appears
  under the URL in the crawl log.

**Remove an item from the search results**
To remove an item from the search results

- Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an
  administrator for the Search service application.
- On the SharePoint Central Administration home page, in the
  Application Management section, click Manage service applications.
- On the Manage Search Applications page, click the Search service
  application.
- On the Search Administration page, in the Queries and Results
  section, click Search Result Removal.
- On the Exclude URLs From Search Results page, in the URLs to remove
  box, type the URLs of the items that you want to remove from the
  search results.
- Click Remove Now.

source https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219587.aspx

Comment: I am trying to do it programmatically from code behind c#.